# How to get exception details for HTTP 400 in ASP.NET Core Razor pages

Tags: error-handling, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I can't figure out how to get details for http 400 exception in ASP.NET Core 6 Razor Pages.

My test:

Program.cs

```c#
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
```

/Pages/Error.cshtml.cs

```c#
public IActionResult OnPost(int statusCode)
{
        var h1 = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        var h2 = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
        var h3 = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();

        logger.LogError(h1?.Error, $"IExceptionHandlerFeature - HTTP {statusCode} was raised on {h1?.Path}");
        logger.LogError(h2?.Error, $"IExceptionHandlerPathFeature - HTTP {statusCode} was raised on {h2?.Path}");
        logger.LogError($"IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature - HTTP {statusCode} was raised on {h3?.OriginalPath}");
  

    return Page();
}
```

For unhandled exceptions it works fine, there is the Error object in "h1" or "h2" with the error details.

But when I (for an example) change value of anti-forgery token field in my another page and make POST request then method OnPost(int statusCode) in /Pages/Error.cshtml.cs is called with statusCode=400. But the "h1" and "h2" objects are null. The "h3" object contains the url but not the Error object.

Where Can I get detailed information about the error source like "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException....." (not only for the AntiForgery, in general)?

**Update 1:**

I figured out I can achieve this with Filter:

Program.cs

```c#
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
                options.Filters.Add<AntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter>()
                );
```

AntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter.cs:

```c#
public class AntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter :  IAlwaysRunResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is IAntiforgeryValidationFailedResult result)
        {
            // log exception
        }
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is IAntiforgeryValidationFailedResult result)
        {
            // log exception
        }
    }
}
```

It's not a good way probably.